# Accessing an additional profile from templates

Tags: python, django

How do I get an additional user profile in template?

When accessing the profile I do this:

`{{ request.user.get_profile.x }}`

... but I have an additional OneToOne profile called UserReferralProfile. How can I access it from templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would simply do:

```
{{ request.user.userreferralprofile.y }}
```

Or if you have specified a `related_name`,

```
class UserReferralProfile(models.Model):
    x = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='referal')
    y = models.CharField()
```

In the template,

```
{{ request.user.referal.y }}
```